# Create a dictionary of unique values of a column in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'ID': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ'], 
'value': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210],
'value2': [2100, 2120, 2130, 2200, 2190, 2210],   
'state': ['init','mid', 'final', 'init', 'mid', 'final'], 
})
```

I want to create dictionary of unique values of the Column 'ID'. I can extract the unique values by:

```
df.ID.unique()
```

But that gives me a list. I want the output to be a dictionary, which looks like this:

```
dict = {0:'ABC', 1: 'XYZ'}
```

If the number of unique entries in the column is n, then the keys should start at 0 and go till n-1. The values should be the names of unique entries in the column

The actual dataframe has 1000s of rows and is often updated. So I cannot maintain the dict manually.

Comment: try enumerate : `d = dict(enumerate(df.ID.unique()))` ? then `print(d)`

Comment: @anky that's a cool enumerate -> dict trick!

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='dict')['ID']`

Comment: @igorkf wrong output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. -

```
dict(enumerate(df.ID.unique()))
```

```
{0: 'ABC', 1: 'XYZ'}
```

Comment: You answer is equal to the comment of @anky

Comment: Can you also add sort?

Comment: @PM0087, sorting based on what? could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant by sorting one of the columns, but already fixed it by actually sorting before doing this. All good, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get unique values for a particular column in dict, try:

```
val_dict = {idx:value for idx , value in enumerate(df["ID"].unique())}
```

Output while printing **val_dict**

> {0: 'ABC', 1: 'XYZ'}